# How to bypass multiple proxy in jmeter

Tags: cmd, proxy, jmeter, jmeter-3.2

I am using the command

```
jmeter -H proxy -P 4145 -N 10.24.27.57;10.5.213.40;10.5.247.126 -u username -a password
```

I want to bypass these 3 proxy `10.24.27.57;10.5.213.40;10.5.247.126`.

How will it work?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it won't work. JMeter relies on [Java Networking Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html) for proxy configuration, which supports only 1 proxy server.

Hard to tell without any further details, but for example you could split your load to 3 machines, each running 1/3 of the load against different proxy.